# How to append a JSON to another JSON

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I am trying to append the new object in the for loop to the request JSON.

this is not working :

```
setCapabilities('default',['1','2','3'])
```

```
export function 
setCapabilities(kaiId:number|"default"|"defaultLeft"|"defaultRight",capabilitiesArr:string[]){ 
    var request:object = {
        type:'setCapabilities',
        kaiId:kaiId
    };
    capabilitiesArr.forEach(element => {
        var obj = {
            element:true
        }
        console.log(obj)
    });

}
```

This is also not working :

```
export function setCapabilities(kaiId:number|"default"|"defaultLeft"|"defaultRight",capabilitiesArr:string[]){ 
    var request:object = {
        type:'setCapabilities',
        kaiId:kaiId
    };
    capabilitiesArr.forEach(element => {
        var obj[element]=true
        console.log(obj)
    });
}
```

I want the output to be as :

```
console.log(request)
```

```
{
type:'setCapabilities',
kaiId:'default',
'1':true,
'2':true,
'3':true
}
```

Comment: Please add some expected input and output.

Comment: Please re-read the forEach in both versions, and try to say what you think should happen? Why the var declaration? Where do you want it to go? You also seem to have some typscript in there, do you want a javascript answer or typescript answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the code in javascript for browser to run the code snippet, but you can convert it to typescript for your use

```js
function setCapabilities(kaiId, capabilitiesArr) {
  var request = {
    type: 'setCapabilities',
    kaiId: kaiId
  }
  var obj = Object.assign({}, request)
  capabilitiesArr.forEach(element => {
    obj[element] = true
  });
  console.log(obj)
}

setCapabilities('default',['1','2','3'])
```

In typescript use below code

```
function setCapabilities(kaiId:number|"default"|"defaultLeft"|"defaultRight",capabilitiesArr:string[]) {
  var request:object = {
    type: 'setCapabilities',
    kaiId: kaiId
  }
  var obj = {...request}
  capabilitiesArr.forEach(element => {
    obj[element] = true
  });
  console.log(obj)
}
```

Comment: how do we change this to typescript ?

Comment: let me do it for you, wait a minute

Comment: I've updated my answer containing the typescript version of the function

Comment: yes, it was giving no index signature error, but I made some changes and fixed it. I added this :  const req = (this.obj as any)